# How to check for a folder inside a particular folder in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am working on a shell script and python script as well. Python script is passing certain parameters to my shell script and then I am using those parameters in my shell script.

Below is my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly MACHINES=(machineB machineC)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/peta/t1_snapshot
readonly FILE_TIMESTAMP=$file_timestamp

// old code which I am using to get the full path of the latest folder in each machine
dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${MACHINES[0]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${MACHINES[1]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

// not sure what should I do here?
dir3=$MAPPED_LOCATION/$FILE_TIMESTAMP
```

In each machine `(machineB and machineC)`, there will be a folder in this format `YYYYMMDD` inside this folder `MAPPED_LOCATION`.

Now what I am trying to do is - I am passing `file_timestamp` from the python script which will be in this form `YYYYMMDD` so now I need to check whether this folder is there inside `MAPPED_LOCATION` folder or not in each machine.

If it is there then print out the full path of that folder for each machine, otherwise exit out of the shell script with non-zero status. If it is not there in any one of the machine, I will exit out of the shell script with a message that this folder is not present in this machine with non zero status.

I am not sure how can I do this check in the shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d="${MAPPED_LOCATION}/$(python_script)" 
[ -d "$d" ] && echo "$d" || exit 1
```

Comment: What is python_script here? And can you add some description which will be useful for my understanding purpose.?

Comment: $(python_script) is your `python_script`

Comment: or it should be `$FILE_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @SSH I don't know - it's your script. By the way, *You* should *know* what it does. I recognize this, you know, though you're using a different username. I remember all the nonsense you went through before to get other people to do this for you. Does your boss know that random people from the internet are writing the code that handles backing up/restoring your datacenters and you have *no idea what it does?*